# how to write this particular query regarding a bus-stop app?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in my database called stops

```
Id  coll-id  busnumber stops
1   v01       900       abc
2   v01       900       bcd
3   v01       14        abc
4   v01       14        bcd
5   v01       14        def
```

The bus basically stops at all the mentioned points, the user is asked to input source and destination. we need to get all the available bus numbers of the buses from source to destination. i've been unable to do so, i need both values to be found in the column stops for a particular bus-number.for example, if the source is abc and the destination bcd, i need to return both 900 and 14, this is just sample data there will be a lot more buses with overlapping routes. help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select, only the rows of the two stops you want. Group by bus number to get the count of matching stops per bus. Only return those that match both stops. `DISTINCT` probably isn't really necessary, but makes sure results are still correct if one stop could be on the route for one bus multiple times.

This approach will also work if you want to get all busses that stop at 3 or 4 stops. Just expand the list of stops and increment the number in the `having` clause accordingly.

```
SELECT
  busnumber
FROM
  stops s
WHERE
  s.stops in ('abc', 'bcd')
GROUP BY
  busnumber
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.stops) = 2
```

Comment: You mean distinct bus number? This gives routes with 2 stops.

Comment: hey , thank you. i tried something similar. i couldn't understand the group by function

Comment: The group by is to get only one result per busnumber and allows you do aggregations per group, like the `COUNT` that follows it.

Comment: @Ben On second thought, no, I really meant stops. This gives routes which have two stops that match the list of stops in the where clause. So this gives you a list of busses you can use to get from 'abc' to 'bcd', which I believe is what was asked. Un'fixed' it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `self join` to get the bus number given two stops

```
   SELECT b1.busnumber 
   FROM stops b1
   JOIN stops b2
   ON b1.busnumber = b2.busnumber
   AND b1.stops ='abc'
   AND b2.stops ='def'
```

Comment: yup, i was thinking of self-join but sort of forgot how :/ thank you!